# Record Types in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

I have two questions here:

1. Is it possible to skip the record type selection box in Lightning?
   I have already done user settings(Default Record Types). The record type box is properly skipped in Classic Mode via this setting.
   However, It has no effect in Lightning.
2. How can I pass recordtype via PageReference Parameters in Lightning?

I have created a custom VisualForce Page for Record Type selection (Since I didnot want all record types to be visible).
I pass the recordtype ID like this in my controller method:

```
    PageReference pageRef = New PageReference('/' + result.getKeyPrefix() + '/e'+ '?nooverride=1');
    //Pass RecordType ID
    pageRef.getParameters().put('RecordType', recordType);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
```

It works fine in classic mode, however, in Lightning, it is picking up a random record type (not even Default one) and showing the corresponding screen.

Am I missing something here?Kindly help.

Comment: As far as I know, `Pagereference` navigation is not supported in Lightning.

Comment: Ok..actually you can call it a visualforce page only where I have used lightning  UI elements like modal box , to give it a look and feel of lightning. And it is rendering perfectly fine in Lightning. So, navigation is fine. Just that it takes no parameters :(

Comment: So, it's still being used in Lightning? Or is this still in Classic?

Comment: I am having same issue. Can you please share the solution if you were able to find any ?